# thor27's steam-login without entering Big Picture

Tags: login, games, lightdm, steam

I've installed [steam-login](https://github.com/thor27/steam-login), which allows me to start Steam as a standalone session directly from the lightdm login. By default, it starts Steam on Big Picture mode, but I would like it to start on regular, windowed mode. Going to settings doesn't work, because "Start on Big Picture" is already turned off, so I guess the solution must involve tweaking some starting config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file containing such configuration is called `steam-de`, the newest version of which is located at https://github.com/thor27/steam-login/blob/master/steam-login/usr/bin/steam-de.

Notice the content of line 63:

```
parameters='-tenfoot -enableremotecontrol'
```

Those are the parameters that make Steam open in Big Picture mode, but luckily the author made it easy to alter.

Firstly, you need to locate `steam-de` on your machine. Go to the terminal and type `whereis steam-de`. You may find, as output, something like `steam-de: /usr/bin/steam-de /usr/bin/X11/steam-de`.

Now we edit the file. In this case, we run:

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/steam-de
```

Then, **change the aforementioned parameters argument to `parameters=''`**. Save (that's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> on nano) and exit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>). If you run `sudo nano /usr/bin/X11/steam-de`, you will notice your change has carried on to that file.

Now just run steam-login as usual and it will boot in windowed mode.

By the way, you may also want to comment line 88, prefixing it with a `#`; it will look like this:

```
# zenity --error --text "Ops! Steam had some trouble to run. That can be a problem with steam itself or with your configuration."
```

This will prevent steam-login from showing an error dialog when you exit steam from the windowed mode. It should, instead, just go straight back to lightdm.